# Access control value from Angular 2 Template

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Is it possible to access the channel_header control from my template like 
   this => _form.controls['headers'].controls[i].controls.channel_header

```
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) 
ngOnInit() {
  this._form = this._fb.group({
       headers: this._fb.array([
           this._fb.group({
               channel_header: ['', Validators.required],
               data_option: ['', Validators.required]  
           })
       ]);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work this way

```
<div>{{_form.get('headers.0.channel_header').value}}</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you could make it work :)

Comment: I needed the index to be dynamic so i added a method to my component to return the formatted string for the _form.get()                                                              getControlValue(index, controlName): string{
        return `headers.${index}.${controlName}`;
 }                                                                                                        .....then in the template I have  <p>{{_form.get(getControlValue(i,'channel_header')).value}}</p>